# Remove background when modal pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery CustomBox modal and all works fine. However, I am trying to ‘hide’ the content div behind the modal once popped up. I then want the content div to reappear again after the modal has closed. Here is the working example:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/doolz77/full/4879c1495e17c1ee199997e08d394cd3/)

I have just been watching the jQuery videos from css-tricks but still having problems trying to get this to work :) Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I want to content div to reappear when the modal is closed via outside the modal screen as well as the actual 'x' button.

EDIT: the actual web page is [here](http://www.akboheim.com/tsc/new.html)

Click on ‘CLICK ME’ and you can see the modal pops up fine, however, I’d like ONLY the background image of the cellar showing, not the page underneath it.

Any suggestions??
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `toggle()` would be a thing for that..but need u to post the code, ur `pen` doesn't work

Comment: Link doesn't work. Please provide standard Codepen link.

Comment: @rockStar Didn't `toggle()` get deprecated?

Comment: @Paulie_D: then would use other :)

Comment: .hide() and .show() and callbacks are your friends :).

Comment: I just edited the link and this one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fadein").click(function(){
      $("#foo").hide();
    });
    $("#showFoo").click(function(){
      $("#foo").show();
    });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/eKEly/)

Edit

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="close" id="close-mod" onclick="$.fn.custombox('close'); myfunction();">&times;</button>
```

JS

```
function myfunction() {
    $("#foo").show();
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#fadein").click(function(){
     $("#foo").hide();
   });
});
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/eKEly/)

**CSS edit to background color opacity of `.custombox-overlay`**

[**Final DEMO**](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/eKEly/)

```
.custombox-show ~ .custombox-overlay {
  background-color: black !important;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works when the modal is closed via the 'x' button, however, not so much when the outside screen is clicked :(  Any suggestions??

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that but the div doesn't reappear when clicked outside the modal.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  All I had to do was place the cellar image like this and it worked. I know its probably not the best solution but I'm OK with it :)

```
.custombox-show ~ .custombox-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    background: url(../images/img.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```